# AADSTS50013: Assertion contains an invalid signature. Reason - The key was not found.,

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to setup an Azure Function with Azure AD B2C. The functions require authorization tied to an Azure AD B2C application.

The Azure AD B2C application has a keys section:

[image]

I used the generated key (M99*****) and put it in the azure functions authentication/authorization settings:

[image]

When I call the function passing in the correct bearers key:

```
[FunctionName("TestMe")]
public static IActionResult Run([
    HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, 
    [Token(Resource="https://graph.microsoft.com", Identity=TokenIdentityMode.UserFromRequest)]string graphToken,
    TraceWriter log)
{
```

I'm not sure what's going on at this poiint other than I'm using the wrong secret key, which begs the quesiton - in Azure AD B2C what is the correct key?

Comment: Are you trying to use a B2C applicaiton which in a B2C tenant  and configrue it for a Function in AD tenant ?

Comment: Yes, everything is set up in the same azure ad b2c directory...

Comment: Is your Function App also in the b2c directory? As I known ， we cannot use B2C App for the authentication of Web/Function App.

Comment: Yeah it's in the directory, I am definitely able to use the B2C app login url to get an id_token which I can pass into the azure function as a authorization bearers token to successfully execute functions...

Comment: I understasnd that.. But the Authentication Feature for Web/Function App is for Azure AD. The application in the configuration should also be the AAD Application.  The AAD app is different from AAD B2C App.  If you need to use the B2C application, you need to configure it in your function itself, Not using this authentication feature. I hope I made clear about this.

Comment: Additonal, the key for those two kind app are different formats.

Comment: I see, so basically Azure AD B2C does not have an implemented system for identifying users? That means I have to write my own, seems like a gross oversight as being able to identify a user calling a function which requires authentication is something I would expect would work..